# 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) and apt-get source

Tags: apt

I am a new Linux user (sorry) and have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS installed.
When trying to update update packages with `sudo apt-get update` but I am gettng errors. And I am quite confused to what is actually wrong here and what I am expected to fix manually and what is typically handled automatically. (The server is pretty new).

```
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ...
```

I see that some requests seem to be going for a Jessie release. Which I assume is related to the errors I am getting. Jessie is an old distribution, so I am unsure to why my my source list look the way it does.

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [109 kB]
Ign:4 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie Release [148 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie Release.gpg [2,420 B]
Ign:7 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie Release.gpg
```

I hope my question is specific enough. I am faced with a lot new technology here and struggle to pin point the source of this issue and how to fix it.

Edit:
A few of you wonder how my sources.list ended up being messed up. I think it was weird too, I am happy i am not the only one thinking that. This is how the server was delivered.. Where someone previously messed up is unknown to me.

This is the full version of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie main
#deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main
#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu

## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
```

Comment: How did your `sources.list` get to be like that? You appear to have both Ubuntu and Debian as your package sources? Was this server upgraded from a previous Ubuntu release?

Comment: Hi Geogrow, it seems like you have added the package repositories from a *different* operating system to your Ubuntu (that other operating system being debian in its "Jessie" version, which has been dead for 5 years). That will not work. If you remember what you did there exactly, please undo it.

Comment: The problem now becomes that your system is "messed up manually" in ways which we cannot know. So, as Panki asked: How did you end up in this situation? What did you *exactly* do?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that sources.list is nonsensical and will not do you any favors:

Debian is not the same as Ubuntu, so packages for debian might simply not work on Ubuntu, or worse, break it. Thus, having debian package sources in your sources.list makes no sense to begin with.

Other things that make no sense are that debian Jessie was dead ("end of life") before Ubuntu jammy or focal came out.

This looks like someone added decades-old debian repos to your sources.list, and because all the packages there were simply older than what was on the ubuntu focal repos, this never was a problem, until the keys with which the debian repo signs their packages ran out of its validity.

This is a pretty good indication that whoever administrated the server before you flew by a principle of "yeah, I don't really understand this article, but there's stuff I can copy and paste, so let's try that; because I don't understand it, I can't roll it back, either".

Long story short: The *easiest* way, long term, probably is just setting up a fresh Ubuntu Jammy, and erasing the existing system in the process – a *properly set up server* will have automatic backup of the data it handles, and you might know which bespoke server applications you need to run on it.
Sadly, it's unlikely that this server was *properly set up*, so that these things are more distributed, and require you to know what you need from the old server. (If you need nothing from what the server had been doing before – stop here. Install fresh. There's no upside to repairing and upgrading a system you don't need. It's much easier to just install a fresh Ubuntu server.)

If you need to keep this server running as is, remove all lines containing the word "debian" from your sources.list. While you're at it, you can also remove all lines referring to "focal" (I think they're already commented out).

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer! What I ended up doing which seem to have solved the issue is to have the maintainer of servers that replace the source file with a correct one used on another properly maintained server of the same distribution.

Comment: that all sounds very "duct taped together" and not at all like a server should be administrated. But it certainly works. It's just not a reflection of consistent administration. One question though: Why are you the one asking here and not the admin, if you are not the admin of your server? It's their job to keep these servers running...